# How to create button menu?

Tags: discord.py

recently started getting acquainted with "[Bot UI Kit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=button#bot-ui-kit)”, and here I got the question of how to create a pagination for embed. Yes, I found on the Internet how to make the contents of the embed, but for my tasks it is necessary that the content does not change, but change View(namely select menu).

[image]

That is, when moving to the next page in the pagination, changes `discord.SelectOption`. Here is the code I use to reflect this interaction that the picture[[guthub](https://github.com/IndiMops/Ganyu-bot/blob/main/cogs/character.py#L68)]:

```py
@app_commands.command()
async def menu(self, interaction: discord.Integration):
    menu = Select(
        placeholder='Choose something...',
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='label1',
                value='1',
                emoji='<:emoji:1052662876948668436>'
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Label2',
                value='2',
                emoji='<:sucrose:1052662935845085214>'
            )
    ]
    )

    first_page = Button(
        emoji='⬅️',
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple,
        disabled=True
    )
    pervision_page = Button(
        emoji='⏮️',
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.green,
        disabled=True
    )
    next_page = Button(
        emoji='⏭️',
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.green
                        )
    last_page = Button(
        emoji='➡️',
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple
    )

    view = View()
    view.add_item(menu)
    view.add_item(first_page)
    view.add_item(pervision_page)
    view.add_item(next_page)
    view.add_item(last_page)
                        
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view)
```

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code. Where is the embed? Please avoid posting links to other websites. Include all necessary related code in the question itself; see [mcve]. What is the problem? Do you get any errors (please post them; you should be getting many)? What are you trying to do? Can you please make it clearer? Where in your code do you 'change' `SelectOption`? And change it to what? Please [edit] your question to improve and it make it clearer, with all code used in the shortest way possible.

Comment: @The Amateur Coder, sorry for replying so late. I reworked the code a little, so this question can be closed, because I otherwise completed the task. But I probably then wanted to know how to track the 'click' event on the button. And after clicking on the button, I wanted to know how to change the data in the `menu` variable, which is in the `menu` function in the `options` argument (sorry, I'm using a translator)